# Dsus4 In A major

Tags: theory, chord-theory

Just curious,

Because A major has 3 sharps (F#,C#,G#), and The notes of Dsus4 are D-G-A, how can you play Dsus4 in A major?

Is Dsus4 not played in the key or A major? Does it get changed to D-G#-A?

Let’s say for example you want to go from the IV chord to the vii* chord, how would you do this?

Thanks In advance

Edit:  I just figured out that sus4 chords don’t exist on any major IV chords. Diatonically speaking.

Comment: It's not clear how IV -> viio fits into your question. There's no inherent reason for Dsus4 to impact that progression.

Comment: The question about IV -> viio might mean, how do you go to viio if the seventh degree has been modified by the Dsus4 chord. The answer is, using a viio chord cancels the temporary chromatic alteration made by the IV sus4, and then the seventh degree G# again. And if that's what the OP means, then this is just one of the dozens of questions where the poster doesn't know about chromatic alterations.

Comment: *Hey Deanie* (written by Eric Carmen, I think it was performed by Shaun Cassidy), the intro goes (from memory): Asus4 A Asus4 A Dsus4 D Esus4 E. It sounds great.

Answer (score 8):

Key means two things

- what the tonic note is
- is the tonic chord major or minor

"Key = A major" means:

- (1) A is the tonic note
- (2) The third above the tonic, when the harmony is at a resting position, is a major third. In other words, **the home chord is an A major chord.**

The key being A major does not mean that a G note must never be played. There can be chromatic alterations and it does not need to change the key. You can even temporarily use an A *minor* chord or anything, as long as you don't lose track of what was home. Here's a chord progression that can be used in the key of A major: A A7 D Bm B7 E7 D7 C#7 F#7 B7 E7 A. It uses all white keys and black keys of the piano, all twelve.

The key signature of A major specifies a default scale that's often used in pieces centered on an A major chord. **Deviations from the default scale are marked with accidentals** in notation. Usually the deviations are short and temporary, and that's why in notation practice, accidentals only apply until the end of the measure.

> Let’s say for example you want to go from the IV chord to the vii*
> chord, how would you do this?

If you mean, how do you use G#dim, if G has been made natural i.e. chromatically altered by the Dsus4 chord, then: the G#dim chord simply cancels the chromatic alteration. It's the same with any chord that uses notes not found in the default scale. If in the key of A major and the A major scale being the default scale, you use a B7 chord before going to E7 for example, then at least for the duration of the B7 chord, the fourth scale degree D is chromatically altered, raised to D#. When you get to E7, the D is returned back to D natural.

Chord symbols are absolute, their notes are not changed whatever the key is said or believed or speculated to be. Dsus4 has D, G and A notes, in every key, and in keyless random chaotic noise.

Answer (score 5):

Dsus4 = D G A regardless what key the surrounding music is in.

There are two explanations for a Dsus4 chord occurring in A major:

1. We've left the key of A major, if only for the duration of that single chord.
2. We're playing a genre of music that admits the ♭7 in a major key. For example, blues routinely employ the ♭7 of their native key. The first four measures of a blues in C major can be (and typically are) C7, and the song is still considered C major.

Answer (score 2):

The 'rules' in music are not 'rules'. They are in the theory stage, which means a lot of them haven't been 'proved' beyond doubt. Hence - music theory.

There is no 'rule' that states 'thou shalt not stray from diatonic notes in a key while performing any music'.

Using any of the five remaining notes from the twelve available has been the case since music began. Humans like to categorise whenever they can, and found that seven notes fit neatly into a key - and can be played consecutively in what is called a scale.

However, a piece in a specific key can, and often will, use some of the *non-diatonic* notes. Also called *chromatics*. They will add a bit of spice to the sound. Their use may, or may not, mean the key has changed. One common variant is the ♭7 you find in the song in the question. It is used extensively in Blues (as Aaron says), and other genres, and occurs in music going back centuries - it's nothing new.

Using any of these chromatics always needs the use of an accidental, as the note is 'out of key', but although if used for many bars after, there *may* have been a key change, most often it's simply a modulation, usually to the next 'key' round the circle of 4ths/5ths. Returning even after one bar.

Would you say that a bar containing A7 - A C♯ E G isn't in key A? Strictly speaking, it could be argued that it's actually key D, but we'd all agree that A7 is found in key A many, many times. There's that G again!

The Dsus4 chord will only ever contain D G and A, in any key at all. The sus bit means it's lost its 3rd, replaced by its 4th, and the 4th of D is G♮. There's also the 'theory' that says *parallel* key notes can be used. Key A minor happens to contain G♮. Voila!

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, that's not what "theory" means, perhaps you are thinking of "hypothesis"?

Answer (score 2):

In classical harmony, the sus4 would normally use diatonic pitches. For example, in a `| Ⅴ | ⅠⅤ 4-3 | viiº6 |` progression in A major, you would prepare the `G#` in the `Ⅴ` chord, suspend it in the `ⅠⅤ` and resolve downward to `F#` as a `Sus4-3`. From there, you could voice lead back to `G#` in the  `vii°6`. Alternatively, it would be also interesting to stick the `viiº6` inside the suspension as a `| Ⅴ | ⅠⅤ 4-- (vii°6) --3|` progression.

Here's an example of a `Sus4-3` in a `ⅠⅤ` chord:

[image: Chain of sus4-3]

A `G♮` would only be used in A major if you could prepare it before hand and modulating to a new key.

Answer (score 2):

> ...I just figured out that sus4 chords don’t exist on any major IV chords. Diatonically speaking

That isn't the "answer" as much as the proper way to start the question. `Dsus4` is not diatonic to `A` major, but you could play that non-diatonic chord without necessarily undermining the sense the music is in `A` major.

> ...Is Dsus4 not played in the key or A major?

You can play it, and then explain it. There can be various ways to explain it: chord borrowing or mode mixture (mixolydian mode), or it could continue and modulate to/tonicize `D`.

The thing that really matters is the *extent to which the music may deviate from plain, diatonic `A` major.* If it's a fleeting moment, there is no reason to say the key has changed. If it's a even mix of changes, the key/mode could be fairly called ambiguous.

There really aren't "can" or "can't do" scenarios. Just various ways to describe things, and whether those descriptions make theoretical sense.

Answer (score 1):

The key of a piece is a framework, not a restriction.  You can stick to diatonic notes, but you don't HAVE to.